# GeoGraphics added to a current GeoGraphics object

Tags: pattern-matching, geographics

I need to make a `GeoGraphics[]` object then save it to disk, move it to another computer where I need to load in the object then add some more `GeoGraphics[]` primitives. Below is a simple example of what I think should work.

**Warning**: The code below will download an image from Google and save it to your hard drive in your `$TemporaryDirectory` location! If you run all the code I do remove the file.

Get an image of one of my favorite camping locations then save it out:

```
loc = {37.4826678, -110.6310902};
geobackdrop = 
  GeoGraphics[GeoCenter -> GeoPosition[loc], 
  GeoServer -> "http://mt0.google.com/vt/lyrs=s,h&x=`2`&y=`3`&z=`1`", 
  GeoRange -> Quantity[2, "Kilometers"], 
  AspectRatio -> 1];
file = FileNameJoin[{$TemporaryDirectory, "Moqui.wl"}];
Save[file, geobackdrop];
ClearAll[geobackdrop];
```

At this point, we should have a `GeoGraphics[]` object on disk. Now lets read it in and try to add a `GeoDisk[]`.

```
 Get[file];
 Cases[{geobackdrop}, 
            GeoGraphics[a_, b___] :> 
            GeoGraphics[{
               GeoDisk[loc, Quantity[.05, "Kilometers"]], a}, b]
             ][[1]]
```

Where is my Disk? Is there a clean way to add items to the `GeoGraphics[]` object I have read off the disk?

Run this to remove the file from your hard drive:

```
  If[FileExistsQ[file], DeleteFile[file]]
  If[Not[FileExistsQ[file]],
     Print["The file is gone!"]]
```

Thank you.

Comment: Is Save/Get part essential for the problem? Is your cases method doing what you expect if you skip save/get?

Comment: Yes the Save/Get is not essential the `Cases[]` and I could have asked the question without it but then I expected the question "Why not just put the `GeoDisk[]` in at the start?"

Comment: To avoid that question add a note that you can't because you can't. It was createad earlier/took a long time/you imported it. Whatever :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The disk is there but it is hard to find because it is rather small and shaded in transparent black. It is easier to spot if you make it its boundary red:

```
Cases[{geobackdrop}, GeoGraphics[a_, b___] :> GeoGraphics[{
     EdgeForm[{Red, Thick}],GeoDisk[loc, Quantity[.05, "Kilometers"]], a}, b]][[1]]
```

[image]

Btw., since this is somewhat counterintuitive:
In order to change the style of the interior of the disk, you may use `GeoStyling`:

```
Cases[{geobackdrop}, GeoGraphics[a_, b___] :> GeoGraphics[{
     GeoStyling[Directive[Opacity[1], Red]],
     GeoDisk[loc, Quantity[.05, "Kilometers"]], a},
    b]
  ][[1]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you I feel rather silly but I did not look closely because I also got the warning: "Graphics is not a Graphics primitive or directive." Did you get this warning?

Comment: No error. Worked like a charm. (version 11.3 on macOS). No need to feel silly. I also didn't find it in the first place. :)

Comment: Thanks. They both work for me also but I do get the warning. (Version 11.3 on Mint Linux)

Comment: Well, if it works (apart from the warning), then you can tell Mathematica to be `Quiet`... :)

Comment: Yes, I have done that before and I'll do it here but it is not clean.

Comment: Ah, in this particular case, you can also use `g = GeoGraphics[{
   GeoStyling[Directive[Opacity[1], Red]],
   GeoDisk[loc, Quantity[.05, "Kilometers"]]
   },
  Options[geobackdrop]
  ]`. All necessary information about `geobackdrop is contained in `Options[geobackdrop]`.

Comment: Yes, it does but that is because it downloads again (or retrieves from cache) the image data. Once I get this to my remote computer without internet it fails.  I think I may open another question that focuses on no internet connection.